# Jquery serivalize doesn't work. Names are given

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I want to get serialized string from all my checkboxes.
Trying to do it this way.

```
var companies=$("input.company").serialize();
console.log($("input.company").serialize());
alert(companies);
```

Here is my html form.

```
    <div id="listOfCompanies"><h1>Список компаний</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" class="company" name="company" value="Microsoft">Microsoft<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="company" name="company" value="Apple">Apple<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="company" name="company" value="Ubisoft">Ubisoft<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="company" name="company" value="sony">sony<br><input type="checkbox" class="company" name="company" value="agilient_technology">agilient_technology<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="company" name="company" value="marvel">marvel<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="company" name="company" value="blizzard">blizzard<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="company" name="company" value="ibm">ibm<br>
</div>
```

Both console and alert give empty string. Any suggestions?

Comment: to be serialized, checkboxes need to be checked: http://jsfiddle.net/3P4BX/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unchecked checkboxes aren't included by the browser, which makes sense really because they have a boolean state -- they're either selected by the user (included) or not selected by the user (not included).**

```
alert($("input.company").prop('checked', true).serialize());
```

See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/x6pfy/).